# Building smart contract

Tags: contract-development, myetherwallet

I am trying to build a simple smart contract following the rules on the website below.

https://medium.com/crypto-currently/build-your-first-smart-contract-fc36a8ff50ca

For some reason after unlocking my wallet I am unable to sign my transaction. I do not receive any error messages and have tried multiple times. Any help?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: The tutorial is quite old. Maybe it is a good idea to find something newer. You may try Truffle-Suite to build, deploy and test your contract.

Answer (score 0):

In the top corner of ether wallet increase the gas price to 99 Gwei and deploy it. This should fix your issue.